# Why would someone use empirical sum instead of numerical integration methods?

Tags: numerical-analysis, integration

In the context of a scientific computing application, using data coming from (powerful) embedded systems, acquiring raw data (but from calibrated acquisition electronics), I have been asked to integrate these data (in RT), with an empirical sum, instead of making use of usual numerical methods. (Important note : even if we are dealing with embedded systems, computational power is not an issue).

When I was asking why not using these usual numerical methods (e.g. Simpson's, midpoint rule, trapezoidal rule, etc.), I could not get any answer. Then, I am wondering why someone would want to perform it this way.

The acquisition application on the embedded system is in C++03, compiled with GCC 4.4.7, the average being performed looking somewhat like this (this code is executed each time the acquisition is performed) :

```
float sum = 0.0; 
for (int i = 0; i < DATA_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++) {
    sum += data[i]
}
sum /= DATA_BLOCK_LENGTH;
```

This snippet gives you an idea of the code performing the average from a trace of the signal received ; the signal usually looking like this most of the time (one or two spikes along the whole signal trace).

[image: Acquisition trace example]
The previous constant, DATA_BLOCK_LENGTH, is usually set to the maximum (2048, which is the size of electronics buffer). The measures are equally-spaced samples.

Comment: FWIW, this is not so different from performing the trapezoidal rule over each sample interval and then summing it all up. Generally, digital signal processing is approached with a different set of mathematical tools (mainly the Z-transform and the DFT) than continuous one-dimensional integral calculus. Probably, this procedure was chosen because its effects in the Z-domain are more readily understood than e.g. Simpson's rule (where the unequal weighting of the samples within each interval has a non-obvious frequency filtering effect in Z-domain).

Comment: In fact, the code snippet is *exactly identical* to using the trapezoidal rule with the exception of the two end intervals. For sufficiently many data points, the end points don't matter, so the code *is* doing the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use the empirical mean if you don't need the additional accuracy of higher-order methods? Anyway, higher-order methods are more accurate only for functions of sufficient smoothness, and it doesn't look like your function is particularly smooth. (Another reason why digital signal processing is not performed via numerical analysis tools.)

Comment: @Wolfgang You are totaly right, I did not see it this way.

Comment: @Rahul Actually, on this project, the accuracy is an issue (but it is not related to this questions but more technical and physical reasons). For the smoothness of the function, I know, this is why I thought naively at first of using adaptative composite integration methods. Regarding what you said about DSP and numerical analysis, I am not sure of what you mean.